# Bypassing the gmail verification pages for automation Test

Tags: python-3.x, robotframework, gmail-api

I'm currently using robotframework to automate test on the web to perform various functions with our app. All of our Test require you login to gmail, the problem is when we run the automation half the time the test fails since google ask for a verification code. I'm using a headless browser cloud solution to run the test. Has anyone run into this issue?

Comment: Have you considered setting up your own mail server for testing? there are also public services you can pay for to create mail accounts for testing.

Comment: No I have not, the purpose of using the gmail servers was to replicate an actual customer logging into our system to test real life scenarios. But on the other hand that's not a bad question to ask either. My gut instinct tells me google is detecting some type automation framework and verifying by the verification code.

Comment: Does your system *require* the use of gmail? I think your gut reaction is correct. The question to ask is, are you needing to test google, or do you just need to test your app?

Answer (score 0):

In link [How to Secure Your Gmail Account With 2-Step Verification](https://www.lifewire.com/secure-your-gmail-account-with-password-and-phone-authentication-1171958)   refer section **Disable 2-Step Verification in Gmail**, . That should help.

Answer (score 0):

**Security Checks should NEVER be BYPASSED**

You can do the following, by following the below approach you would be merely taking another option of verification(THIS IS NOT BYPASS).

go to

1. https://myaccount.google.com/
2. Search bar - search for "app  passwords"
3. Register your app as one of the below cases and generate password, use the same for your log-ins.

Register your app as any one of the following, I suggest you register as either mail/custom app and then proceed with your testing.

1. Mail
2. Calendar
3. Contacts
4. Youtube
5. Custom

[image]

**Less secure apps & your Google Account**

Check out this [link](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255?hl=en) if nothing works, and use this as the last resort.